# Oracle Database Mobile Server first steps

Tags: database, mobile, synchronization

I download jdeveloper studio edition and install it in C:\Oracle\Middleware
then I install weblogic instance using C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\common\bin\config.exe
to C:\myproject\domains\myweblogic

Then download [DMS_11.1.0.0.0_WINDOWS.zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-mobile-server/downloads/index.html) and install it to C:\Oracle\Middleware\Mobile.

thereafter cant start
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Mobile\Mobile\Server\bin\runmobileserver.bat

unless i change the variable to this batch file
set DOMAIN_DIR=C:\myproject\domains\myweblogic

what do I do next to see that it works?
is there a simple example that creates a sigle table and synchronized between server and mobile clients?

very difficult to find information on this technology. interfere very popular tags (Oracle, Database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Database Mobile Server directly in the WebLogic directory, you will not need to edit the batch file. For instance, I believe the default install directory is:

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3
```

So if you used the default install directory, you would install Database Mobile Server there, with no added 'Mobile' or other directory. If you chose to install WebLogic elsewhere, then replace the above with that directory.

There is another small issue to be aware of.

> The installer will give you warning about installing in a non-empty
>   directory. You should click through the warning. This is a known issue
>   documented in the Release Notes.

Regarding your other question about a demo, there is a Java demo found in

```
<MOBILE_HOME>\Mobile\Server\demos\consolidator_api
```

You will need to download a client and perform a sync, which is documented here:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E22663_01/doc.11100/e22681/instsqlite.htm#BABGAACI

I hope that helps, good luck with your project. Let me know if you have further questions.

Eric Jensen, Oracle PM

Comment: tnks, I did not expect to hear you on the thread... I'm a little moved and stack, so i asked on otn (https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2312731&tstart=0)